# javascript function not called on pageload after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I use following function in my ASP.NET page_load function to load a javascript function in my startup (I use masterpage):

```
((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("Body")).Attributes["onload"] = "initialize()";
```

it seems that my javascript function is not called after postback, what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` instead

```
string myscript = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+
        "divTimer();" +
        "initialize();" +
    "</script>";

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock( this.GetType(), "myscript", myscript);
```

Comment: I doesn't work, in fact I have to call two functions on startup: 1)             ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "divTimer", "divTimer();", true); which runs , and 2nd one: ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "initialize", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">initialize()</script>"); which is not called with with this new method

Comment: initialize(); forgot ; after function call

Comment: can you please explain it more Boriss?

Comment: are you using c# or vb.net or what?

Comment: I use C# for my ASP.NET web app

Comment: I have updated my answer. You should check your browser's console if there is any JavaScript error e.g. missing semi-colons